# Store Audio file and retrieve URL from AWS S3 using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm unable to store response from ElevenLabs API to (as mp3 or mpga) onto my AWS S3. What's the correct way to do it?

How to Store binary data as .mp3 file on S3 and retrieve URL?

I receive following error:

'The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Promise',
stack: 'TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Promise\n' +
'    at Function.from (node:buffer:324:9)\n' +
'    at file:///var/task/script.js:420:32\n' +
'    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)'

Help highly appreciated!

```
   app.post('/convert-to-voice', async (req, res) => {
  // createNewVoice()


  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'xi-api-key': process.env.XIAPIKEY,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      text: 'Hi there',
      voice_settings: {
        similarity_boost: 0.5,
        stability: 0.5
      }
    })
  };


  try {
    const response = await fetch(url_main, options);
    const audioBuffer = Buffer.from(response.arrayBuffer());

 

// store something
await s3.putObject({
  Body: audioBuffer,
  Bucket: s3Bucket,
  Key: "some_files/new_file1",
}).promise()


 const newurl = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
  Bucket: s3Bucket,
  Key: "some_files/new_file1",
  Expires: 900 // Set the expiration time in seconds
});

console.log('Public URL:', newurl);

// Send the public URL in the response
res.json({ newurl });
```